# Do I need to escape values when using EntityRepository::findBy()?

Tags: escaping, doctrine-orm

When using Doctrine2's `EntityRepository::findBy()` do I still need to escape values I pass in?

```
$em->getRepository('User')->findBy(array('name' => $_POST['name']));
                                                   ^ need to escape?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **no, you don't**.

Long answer: escaping is a low-level database concern which a higher-level [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Doctrine abstracts for you. When working with Doctrine, you should only be concerned about querying your Domain Model, not about how that will be translated into the underlying persistence technology (in this case, a SQL query).

Detailed info about Doctrine ORM Security can be found [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html).

Answer (score 0):

A database library naturally falls touches the class of SQL injection security vulnerabilities. You should read the following information carefully to understand how Doctrine can and cannot help you to prevent SQL injection.

In general you should assume that APIs in Doctrine are not safe for user input. There are however some exceptions.

The following APIs are designed to be SAFE from SQL injections:

- For `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection#insert($table, $values, $types)`, `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection#update($table, $values, $where, $types)` and `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection#delete($table, $where, $types)` only the array values of `$values` and `$where`. The table name and keys of $values and $where are **NOT** escaped.
- `Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder#setFirstResult($offset)`
- `Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder#setMaxResults($limit)`
- `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform#modifyLimitQuery($sql, $limit, $offset)` for the `$limit` and `$offset` parameters.

Consider ALL other APIs to be not safe for user-input:

- Query methods on the Connection
- The QueryBuilder API
- The Platforms and SchemaManager APIs to generate and execute DML/DDL SQL statements

To escape user input in those scenarios use the `Connection#quote()` method.

source: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html

Comment: Downvoted, sorry. This answer is valid for dbal, not doctrine ORM (referred to in the question). See [Doctrine ORM security](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/security.html)!